# Vertically align content with different sizes of image using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

How I can achieve vertical alignment if one of my image has less height then other. Also rearrange content for < 768px devices.

[image: **Layout**]

[**Codeply**](https://www.codeply.com/go/59bWvc4FOt)

```
.order-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.order-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 250px;
}

.order-image {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px)   {
    .order-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 80px;
        min-width: 450px;
    }

    .order-flex {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the top part of the layout. I think you can figure out the bottom part yourself now.

```css
.order-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.order-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  min-height: 200px;
  max-width: 120px;
}

.order-image {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.txt {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="order-flex">
  <div class="order-wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50" />
    <div class="txt">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100" />
    <div class="txt">text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="order-wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100" />
    <div class="txt">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```